# An Excel code to search data from command button

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried to make a button which searches through a selection of data on one sheet for a ID number then returns the corresponding data in the row after onto a different sheet. I thought i had it sorted but this just wont work and have run out ideas.
Any help would be appreciated.
see code below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim Userentry As String
Dim DataRange As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim location As Integer
Dim ws, ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet4")

With TextBox2
     Userentry = .Value
End With

Range("A36").Value = Userentry

For i = 2 To ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If LCase(Cells(i, 1).Value) = Userentry Then ws1.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Cells(i, 2).Value
Next i

For i = 2 To ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If LCase(Cells(i, 1).Value) = Userentry Then ws1.Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Cells(i, 3).Value  
Next i

For i = 2 To ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If LCase(Cells(i, 1).Value) = Userentry Then ws1.Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Cells(i, 4).Value    
Next i

For i = 2 To ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If LCase(Cells(i, 1).Value) = Userentry Then ws1.Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Cells(i, 5).Value
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd throw in two possible solutions, with the goal to minimize execution time (should it be an issue)

**solution 1**

here you're still actually looping through column A cells but:

- only if there's at least one matching value
- considering non empty cells with text values only

  `

  ```
  Option Explicit

  Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

  Dim Userentry As String, firstAddr As String
  Dim ws1 As Worksheet
  Dim f As Range

  Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet4")
  Userentry = TextBox2.Value
  ws1.Range("A36").Value = Userentry

  With Sheets("Sheet1")
      With .Range("A1:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)'<~~ consider column "A" cells with text values down to the LAST non empty one
          Set f = .Find(What:=Userentry, LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
          If Not f Is Nothing Then '<~~ loop only if there's at least one matching value
              firstAddr = f.Address
              Do
                  ws1.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 4).Value = _
                            f.Offset(, 1).Resize(1, 4).Value
                  Set f = .FindNext(f)
              Loop While f.Address <> firstAddr
          End If
      End With
  End With

  End Sub
  ```

  `

---

**solution 2**

this avoids looping at all, but at the "expense" of sorting rows

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim Userentry As String
    Dim countVal As Long
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet

    Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet4")
    Userentry = TextBox2.Value
    ws1.Range("A36").Value = Userentry

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        With .Range("A1:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) '<~~ consider column "A" cells down to the LAST non empty one
            countVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Cells, Userentry) '<~~ count matching values
            If countVal > 0 Then '<~~ if any then ...
                .Resize(, 5).Sort key1:=.Range("A1"), order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo '<~~ ... sort columns "A" to "E" by column "A" values...
                 ws1.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(countVal, 4).Value = .Find(What:=Userentry, LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues).Offset(, 1).Resize(countVal, 4).Value '<~~ ... and copy/paste values
            End If
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

if you should ever mind having Sheet1 rows sorted, then here's the "patch"

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim Userentry As String
    Dim countVal As Long
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim helperCol As Range

    Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet4")
    Userentry = TextBox2.Value
    ws1.Range("A36").Value = Userentry

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set helperCol = .UsedRange.Columns(.UsedRange.Columns.Count + 1) '<~~ set a helper column "out of the town" not to interfere with data already there
        With .Range("A1:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) '<~~ consider column "A" cells down to the LAST non empty one
            countVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Cells, Userentry) '<~~ count matching values
            If countVal > 0 Then '<~~ if any then ...
                With Intersect(.Rows.EntireRow, helperCol) '<~~ consider helper column rows corresponding to your data ones
                    .Formula = "=ROW()" '<~~ place an ascending index to every row
                    .Value = .Value '<~~ get rid of formulas, otherwise subsequent sorting would have no effect on their result
                End With
                .Resize(, helperCol.Column).Sort key1:=.Range("A1"), order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo '<~~ ... sort columns "A" to "helpercol" rows by column "A" values...
                 ws1.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(countVal, 4).Value = .Find(What:=Userentry, LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues).Offset(, 1).Resize(countVal, 4).Value '<~~ ... copy/paste values ...
                .Resize(, helperCol.Column).Sort key1:=helperCol, order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo '<~~ ... and sort columns "A" to "helpercol" rows back by "helpercol" values
                helperCol.Clear '<~~ finally clear "helpercol" column
            End If
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, this has been bugging me. Does this allow for the search results to be displayed on a different sheet? Need it to be able to find all data relating to a ID in the database sheet to be viewed form the main page. Does that make sense?

Comment: All those solutions do what you asked for: lookup in "Sheet1" column "A" for the ID retrieved by TextBox2 copies the first four cells in the matching row and pastes their value from first non blank cell in column "F" in "Sheet4"

Comment: Yeah i realized after i had written the reply, your help was appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: you are welcome. if my answer fulfilled your question then please mark it as accepted. thank you

Comment: @Tom85: didn't my solution answer you question?

Comment: just _"click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in"_. see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim Userentry As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim ws, ws1 As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet4")


    Userentry = TextBox2.Value
    ws1.Range("A36").Value = Userentry

    For i = 2 To ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If LCase(ws.Cells(i, 1).Value) = Userentry Then 
            ws1.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 4).Value = _
                      ws.Cells(i, 2).resize(1, 4).Value
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Just want to say thank you got it all working now. :-)